# Stop plot on a point defined by intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use `plot` for drawing a path defined using complex polar definition. Currently I plot it using a large domain then I define the intersection with a circle. 
Now I want to stop the plot on the intersection point. How can I do this? I can easily compute the coordinate of the intersection point? So I try to use `range` or `xrange` options but they don't work with none parametric function used to plot.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shapes.geometric,intersections}

\usepackage[active,float]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} 

\begin{document}
%% Parametres
%module
\def\ENGmodule {0.4}
%nb dents
\def\ENGdents {30}
%angle de pression
\def\ENGanglepression {20}
%calculs normalisés
%rayon et diamètre primitifs
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonprimitif}{\ENGmodule*\ENGdents/2}
%rayon et diamètre de base
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonbase}{\ENGrayonprimitif*cos(\ENGanglepression)}
%saillie
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGsaillie}{1*\ENGmodule}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonsaillie}{\ENGrayonprimitif+\ENGsaillie}
%pas primitif
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGpasprimitif}{pi*\ENGmodule}

%%Utils
%fonction conversion degré en radian
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{degtorad}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1*pi/180}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{radtodeg}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1*180/pi}}
%fonction involute
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{involute}{1}{\pgfmathparse{tan(#1)-degtorad(#1)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{involuted}{1}{\pgfmathparse{radtodeg(involute(#1))}}

%%Courbes
%polaire flancs dents
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{flancangle}{3}{\pgfmathparse{involuted(#1)+#3*(#2-1)*radtodeg(\ENGpasprimitif/\ENGrayonprimitif)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{flancpolaire}{1}{\pgfmathparse{\ENGrayonbase/cos(#1)}}

%%% Début dessin
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines,step=1mm,gray!50!white] (-1.5*\ENGrayonbase,-1.5*\ENGrayonbase) grid (1.5*\ENGrayonbase,1.5*\ENGrayonbase);
%
\coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
%
\begin{scope}
  \draw[red!50!black,name path=cerclesaillie] (orig) circle (\ENGrayonsaillie);
  \draw [domain=0:40, blue,name path=flA]  plot ({flancangle(\x,1,1)} : {flancpolaire(\x)} );
  \draw [domain=0:40, blue,name path=flB]  plot ({-flancangle(\x,1,-1)+radtodeg(\ENGpasprimitif/\ENGrayonprimitif)/2} : {flancpolaire(\x)} );
  \path[name intersections={of={flA} and cerclesaillie, by={A}}];
  \path[name intersections={of={flB} and cerclesaillie, by={B}}];

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Current result (in blue the lines I want to stop on the intersection point with the red line):**

[image]

Comment: Don't forget that you can and should [*accept* the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/80176) that best solves the question! Our reputations depend on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `\clip` rather than by computation. See below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shapes.geometric,intersections}

\usepackage[active,float]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} 

\begin{document}
%% Parametres
%module
\def\ENGmodule {0.4}
%nb dents
\def\ENGdents {30}
%angle de pression
\def\ENGanglepression {20}
%calculs normalisés
%rayon et diamètre primitifs
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonprimitif}{\ENGmodule*\ENGdents/2}
%rayon et diamètre de base
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonbase}{\ENGrayonprimitif*cos(\ENGanglepression)}
%saillie
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGsaillie}{1*\ENGmodule}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonsaillie}{\ENGrayonprimitif+\ENGsaillie}
%pas primitif
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGpasprimitif}{pi*\ENGmodule}

%%Utils
%fonction conversion degré en radian
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{degtorad}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1*pi/180}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{radtodeg}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1*180/pi}}
%fonction involute
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{involute}{1}{\pgfmathparse{tan(#1)-degtorad(#1)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{involuted}{1}{\pgfmathparse{radtodeg(involute(#1))}}

%%Courbes
%polaire flancs dents
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{flancangle}{3}{\pgfmathparse{involuted(#1)+#3*(#2-1)*radtodeg(\ENGpasprimitif/\ENGrayonprimitif)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{flancpolaire}{1}{\pgfmathparse{\ENGrayonbase/cos(#1)}}

%%% Début dessin
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines,step=1mm,gray!50!white] (-1.5*\ENGrayonbase,-1.5*\ENGrayonbase) grid (1.5*\ENGrayonbase,1.5*\ENGrayonbase);
%
\coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
%
  \draw [red!50!black,name path=cerclesaillie] (orig) circle (\ENGrayonsaillie);
\begin{scope}
  \clip (orig) circle (\ENGrayonsaillie);
  \draw [domain=0:40, blue,name path=flA]  plot ({flancangle(\x,1,1)} : {flancpolaire(\x)} );
  \draw [domain=0:40, blue,name path=flB]  plot ({-flancangle(\x,1,-1)+radtodeg(\ENGpasprimitif/\ENGrayonprimitif)/2} : {flancpolaire(\x)} );
  \path[name intersections={of={flA} and cerclesaillie, by={A}}];
  (A) circle (2pt);
  \path[name intersections={of={flB} and cerclesaillie, by={B}}];

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've moved the red circle outside the `scope`, then within the `scope` duplicated the circle (without `draw`ing it) and set it as a clipping path for the other elements within the `scope`.

The result I get: [image]

To fill the area between the two blue lines you can connect the two paths and use `\fill`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shapes.geometric,intersections}

\usepackage[active,float]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} 

\begin{document}
%% Parametres
%module
\def\ENGmodule {0.4}
%nb dents
\def\ENGdents {30}
%angle de pression
\def\ENGanglepression {20}
%calculs normalisés
%rayon et diamètre primitifs
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonprimitif}{\ENGmodule*\ENGdents/2}
%rayon et diamètre de base
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonbase}{\ENGrayonprimitif*cos(\ENGanglepression)}
%saillie
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGsaillie}{1*\ENGmodule}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGrayonsaillie}{\ENGrayonprimitif+\ENGsaillie}
%pas primitif
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ENGpasprimitif}{pi*\ENGmodule}

%%Utils
%fonction conversion degré en radian
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{degtorad}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1*pi/180}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{radtodeg}{1}{\pgfmathparse{#1*180/pi}}
%fonction involute
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{involute}{1}{\pgfmathparse{tan(#1)-degtorad(#1)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{involuted}{1}{\pgfmathparse{radtodeg(involute(#1))}}

%%Courbes
%polaire flancs dents
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{flancangle}{3}{\pgfmathparse{involuted(#1)+#3*(#2-1)*radtodeg(\ENGpasprimitif/\ENGrayonprimitif)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{flancpolaire}{1}{\pgfmathparse{\ENGrayonbase/cos(#1)}}

%%% Début dessin
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines,step=1mm,gray!50!white] (-1.5*\ENGrayonbase,-1.5*\ENGrayonbase) grid (1.5*\ENGrayonbase,1.5*\ENGrayonbase);
%
\coordinate (orig) at (0,0);
%
  \draw [red!50!black,name path=cerclesaillie] (orig) circle (\ENGrayonsaillie);
\begin{scope}
  \clip (orig) circle (\ENGrayonsaillie);
  \fill [domain=0:40, blue,name path=flA]  plot ({flancangle(\x,1,1)} : {flancpolaire(\x)} ) -- plot [domain=40:0] ({-flancangle(\x,1,-1)+radtodeg(\ENGpasprimitif/\ENGrayonprimitif)/2} : {flancpolaire(\x)} );
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this: [image]

Note: This approach still avoids calculating the intersection points of the red and blue line.

Comment: Thank you it a good idea. I didn't think about it. But one idea after this process will be to obtain if I can a closed path to fill it. And for this reason if I can define a path that stop on the intersection point it will be better for me.

Comment: What do you want filled? the region between the two blue curves?

Comment: On this question I only present one part of final drawing. The purpose of this drawing is to draw standard gears. Here I only consider the draw of a tooth. After that, I will repeat the tooth to obtain a gear and I will fill the gear. So, for the beginning, the idea will be to feel the space between the blue lines.

Comment: I've updated my answer!